# What causes Cometd to timeout a session so soon?

Tags: websocket, cometd

I'm having trouble with a websocket client connecting to our Cometd server. I can see it is connecting ok and the handshake is good. But after 160 ms, Cometd thinks the session is timed out and removes it.

```
05:45:45.597 [00003] INFO  - canHandshake() result true
05:45:45.597 [00003] INFO  - Websocket session-added : 86db64o1yu7v5elbwdkgg595e
05:45:45.597 [00003] INFO  - Registering websocket session : session {id=86db64o1yu7v5elbwdkgg595e,cid=0,appId=GMCN01,rid=90C3301D-0295-633
05:45:45.598 [00003] INFO  - Registering websocket session : 86db64o1yu7v5elbwdkgg595e for registrationId 90C3301D-0295-6336-351C-45C8884DD
05:45:45.598 [00003] INFO  - storing session info for client 0 @ with host http://10.200.1.87:8081/websocket/transmit?sId=86db64o1yu7v5elbw
05:45:45.605 [00003] INFO  - << {minimumVersion=1.0, supportedConnectionTypes=[websocket, callback-polling, long-polling], successful=true,
05:45:45.606 [00003] INFO  - <  {minimumVersion=1.0, supportedConnectionTypes=[websocket, callback-polling, long-polling], successful=true,
05:45:46.135 [00004] INFO  - >  {connectionType=websocket, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=86db64o1yu7v5elbwdkgg595e} 86db64o1yu7v5elbwdkgg
05:45:46.136 [00004] INFO  - >> {connectionType=websocket, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=86db64o1yu7v5elbwdkgg595e}
05:45:46.136 [00004] INFO  - << {successful=true, advice={interval=0, reconnect=retry, timeout=30000}, channel=/meta/connect}
05:45:46.136 [00004] INFO  - <  {successful=true, advice={interval=0, reconnect=retry, timeout=30000}, channel=/meta/connect}
05:45:46.296 [00007] INFO  - Removing session 86db64o1yu7v5elbwdkgg595e - last connect 160 ms ago, timed out: true <--- THIS IS VERY ODD
05:45:46.296 [00007] INFO  - Websocket session-removed : (t/o=true) 86db64o1yu7v5elbwdkgg595e
```

My own test client appears to work ok, but perhaps because I am closer to the servers and the delay is not as much. The client that is failing is in another region. But the logs do not indicate any latency. The 160 ms timeout seems way too small.

I'm using Java Cometd 2.6.0 embedded with jetty 8.1.12.

I'm thinking there is a setting for the timeout that is too small, but not sure which one controls this, or if there are other reasons behind the timeout.

Anyone else seen this or can explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly, I found the ws.maxInterval was set to 25 instead of 25000. That was the issue.